# Must I explicitly show the types in the parameter pack when instantiate a template?

Tags: c++, parameter-pack

I got a example to illustrate my question:

```
#include <utility>

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(int i) {}
};

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
class Bar {
 public:
  T t;
  Bar(Args &&... args) : t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

and if I want to instantiate this template:

```
Bar<Foo> foo(1);
```

the compiler throw an error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Bar<Foo>::Bar(int)’
```

So I have to write to this:

```
Bar<Foo, int> foo(1);
```

This is annoying, especially if I got some classes which have a long list of parameters.

So is there any way I can get rid of explicitly showing the types in the parameter packs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to constructor to forward, make *that* a template

```
template<typename T>
class Bar {
 public:
  T t;
  template<typename ...Args>
  Bar(Args &&... args) : t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

We normally only care about the types of the arguments during the initialization of `t`, anyway.

Comment: Additional care might be done for copy constructor: `Bar(Bar&)` would match that template constructor instead of expected `Bar(const Bar&)`.

Comment: In this case the `t(t(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` will fail if instantiate `Bar(Bar&)`, I think I can use the deduce trick, but it seems that the constructing of `t` is after when deduce is finished, so I can't play the deduce trick, any suggestions?

Comment: @ravenisadesk - I don't know what you mean by the "deduce trick", but there are workarounds. There's in fact a question devoted to that very problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288243/817643